# One activity for multiple xml layouts and the back button kills the one activity

Tags: xml, android-activity, back

I am developing a very simple android application that has very little java in it. It is an informational app that does nothing but shows text and pictures about things. It has buttons that lead you through different categories and to the information at the end. It has one activity, and from that activity it calls different layouts. I am using the "android:OnClick=""" method in xml to call the different layouts from the buttons. I am using soft back buttons which I don't mind but apparently is bad practice. 
The problem is that when I hit the hard back button, it ends the one activity and kills the whole app and when the orientation changes, it always goes back to the starting layout associated with the one activity. I need some guidance as to if I should redo my entire app in a different way, or somehow track what layout I am in so it knows what to go back to. I've tried creating a separate activity for each layout and when I click the button, it seems to take longer to load than the way I am currently doing it and plus it's not as simple.

My Code Example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/audiocablesbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="audiocables"
    android:text="@string/audiocablesbuttontext" />



    public void audiocables(View v) {
    setContentView(R.layout.audiocables);
    }
```